# Getting to a number with the smallest number of steps.

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

An agent acts on a set $A$ of positive integers by fiddling with the following process.

$\bullet$ Initialize $j = 0$, $A = \{1\}$, some given natural number $n$.

$\bullet$ If $x,y \in A$ then you can append the set $A$ with the number $x+y$ and increase $j$ by $1$, if $n \in A$ then return $j$.

The agent strives to output the smallest $j$ which we will call $W(n)$.

Find $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log_{2}(W(n))}{\log_{2}(n)}$. I know that it is at most $2$ due to the reason below.

I know that if $n$ is of the form $2^{a_{d}}+2^{a_{d-1}}+...+2^{a_{1}}$ where $a_{d}>a_{d-1}...>a_{1}\geq 0$ then the agent can arrive at this number in almost $a_{d}+d-1$ steps.

Comment: Interestingly, $W(129) = W(130) = \cdots = W(256) = 8$ and $W(257) = W(258) = \cdots W(512) = 9$, and this pattern continues...

Comment: $129 = 2^7+1$ should indeed be reached by $8$ steps.